# Partial derivative notation confusion

Tags: partial-derivative, fluid-dynamics

Consider the two-dimensional fluid flow represented by the Lagrangian transformation

\begin{equation}
    \vec{u} = \vec{X}(\vec{a}, \tau) = (a+\Gamma b \tau , b)
\end{equation}

where $\vec{x} = (x,y), \vec{a} = (a,b) , \Gamma = constant$

Compute the Lagrangian velocity field:

\begin{equation}
    \vec{v}(\vec{a}, \tau) = \frac{\partial \vec{X}(a, \tau)}{\partial \tau}
\end{equation}

This professor I have uses different mathematical notation that I am used to and for some reason this question is tripping me up when I feel like it is really easy

Comment: If you have a function $f(x,y)$, do you know how to find its partial derivative $\partial f/\partial y$?